# AudioPlayer "PlaybackNearlyFinished" Request of Alexa Skills Kit, Not Working

Tags: aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I've written an Alexa Skill that uses a Lambda Function to play unique audio from a given URL.

The Intent called "PlayAudio" is working and plays the first audio item from our JSON-formatted API.

The Intent called "PlaybackNearlyFinished" does not work, aka, does not play the audio file I am feeding it. Can anybody crack exactly why this doesn't work?

Here is a section from my Lambda Function, which contains the two Intents:

```
Fact.prototype.intentHandlers = {
    "PlayAudio": function (event, context, response) {
          fetchEnseParse("/latest", function(body) {
            if(body == "error") {
            } 
            else {
                var directives = body.enses.map(function(ense) {
                    var a = ense[1].fileUrl;
                    return {
                         'playBehavior': 'REPLACE_ALL', 
                         'audioItem': 
                             {
                                 'stream': 
                                     {
                                         'url': 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/media.ense.nyc/enses/2017_01_13T16_57_20.190Z/30312/0', 
                                         'token': '33529', 
                                         'offsetInMilliseconds': 0
                                     }
                             }, 
                             'type': 'AudioPlayer.Play'
                    };
                })
            }
            var jsonresponse = {
                'outputSpeech': {
                     'text': '', 
                     'type': 'PlainText'
                    }, 
                'directives': [directives[0]]
            };     
            response.justUseThisJsonPlease( { response: jsonresponse } );
        });
    },


    "AudioPlayer.PlaybackNearlyFinished" : function(event, context, response) {
            var second = 
            {
              "type": "AudioPlayer.Play",
              "playBehavior": "REPLACE_ENQUEUED",
              "audioItem": {
                "stream": {
                  "url": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/media.ense.nyc/enses/violetindigoviolet/30034/0",
                  "token": "33530",
                  "offsetInMilliseconds": 0
                }
              }
            }
            response.justUseThisJsonPlease( { response: second } );
    },
```

Answer (score 5):

It seems that you are including outputSpeech in your response.

This is okay for regular intents, but not for AudioPlayer requests, per this page:
https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/custom-audioplayer-interface-reference

And this note specifically:
[image]

Seeing the exact payload can help as well. You can use to test it locally and get those:
https://bespoken.tools/blog/2016/08/24/introducing-bst-proxy-for-alexa-skill-development

You should be seeing an additional request from Alexa, SystemExceptionEncountered, that should provide more information about what was wrong. It will send this when there is improper response to an AudioPlayer request.

Comment: Hi John. I appreciate your help. I am using outputSpeech in the "PlayAudio" Intent, but I am not using it when I handle the "PlaybackNearlyFinished" request. So I don't think this is the problem.

Comment: Hmm....well, I don't think the REPLACE_ALL is the cause of the problem, but have you considered using ENQUEUE instead? You will also need to include the expectedPreviousToken then as part of the stream object. That will set the stream to play next as opposed to stoping the current stream and starting the new one. Additionally, are you getting an error back from Alexa, such as SystemExceptionEncountered? That should contain more information.

Comment: Hmm...and actually looking at it again, are you wrapping your second response in a directives array? It appears that may be the issue.

Comment: Thanks. I just tried ENQUEUE and feeding in the token from the first audio stream, and it didn't work. Does a PlaybackNearlyFinished request automatically get sent to the skill when the first audio stream is nearing completion? How can I see if my skill is receiving this request? Additionally, could it have something to do with setting PLAY_MODE, or with the session ending itself after the first audio stream is played. Thanks.

Comment: Did you see my comments about the directives array? The response to PlaybackNearlyFinished needs to contain a directives array just like the your response to the Play intent. And the proxy tool I linked to will allow you to debug your skill locally on your machine, including seeing all the requests and responses going back and forth.

Comment: I see. I'll give that a go. Thank you.

Comment: I was able to go into the CloudLogs and find that the PlaybackNearlyFinished request is never actually being sent by Alexa. The docs say that once Alexa begins playing audio these AudioPlayer requests send automatically, but I guess not? Any thoughts on this. I appreciate it. I've also downloaded and tried to run the bespoken tools. Very thorough work on that!

Comment: It should come a few seconds before the current audio completes. I did a lot of my initial testing with it using a very short audio file - in the case, it shows up almost immediately after playback starts, which makes it easier to debug.

Comment: Facing the Same Problem @Ingrid.  I wrote a basic Audio Player sample code using alexa-sdk.  PlaybackNearlyFinished is not calling at the end of the stream. It is just calling as soon as Alexa.PlaybackStarted event is fired. I want to load the next audio but PlayBackNearlyFinished is not calling at the end of stream. My Audio is 5-30 minites long. 
PlayBackNearlyFinished is not triggering at the end of the stream. I am not able to load my audio url beacuse PlayBackNearlyFinished is not getting called.

Comment: Where you able to resolve this? I am facing a similar issue with the PlaybackStopped request.