# Alexa to ask user something after playback has finished

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

So before I even go into my issue, I've looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41641008/audioplayer-playbacknearlyfinished-request-of-alexa-skills-kit-not-working). Basically all I am trying to do is simply just play some audio, when the audio is finished, I just want Alexa to ask the user something. That's it. When I try to emit `:ask` I get the `The following directives are not supported: Reponse may not contain an output speech, Response may not have shouldEndSession set to false`

Okay, and the SO link I posted above is what I found after googling that. So is there honestly absolutely no way for Alexa to say/ask something after audio has finished?? If so, that is absolutely absurd, is there ANY workaround for that?

Here's my code for relevance:

```
'PlaybackFinished' : function() {
    console.log('The stream comes to an end');
  //here lets get the name, and start scenario 3.
  this.emit('PostMissionRequest');
},
'PostMissionRequest': function() {
  var db = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
  var params = {
    TableName: "ALP-Infusion-Adventures",
    Key: {
      "UIUD": "1"
    }
  };

  var self = this;

  this.response.speak('Stream ended').audioPlayerStop();

  db.get(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      ...
    } else {
      console.log("GetItem succeeded! Results:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
      var res = data.Item;
      self.response.speak('this is a test');
      self.emit(':ask', `Nice job completing your mission, ${res.UName}! Would you like to plan your next mission?`)
      self.emit(':responseReady');
    }
  });
},
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/audioplayer-interface-reference.html#playbacknearlyfinished), you can not, but you could enqueue an MP3 of the speech that you want Alexa to say. In your case, instead of `this.response.speak('Stream ended')` you could have an MP3 recording of that and ENQUEUE it in your `PostMissionRequest` handler